# reversing non-zero-initialized chars in array

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

I have an array that is of the form

```
{'1', '3', '2', '\0', '\0'}
```

i.e. - it has been zero initialized, and some amount of values (starting from the beginning) will have values other than `'\0'`

I would like to come up with a function that reverses the part of the array that is not `'\0'`. For example, the above array would turn into:

```
{'2', '3', '1', '\0', '\0'}
```

However, I am having trouble wrapping my brain around how to do this, since I am relatively new to array manipulation. Could someone help? Thanks :)

Comment: Please show some attempt to solve the problem, we're not just going to write it for you. This is obviously homework, and you'll never learn if you don't tryy.

Comment: I mean, it's part of a homework problem, but it's definitely not the part that's supposed to be hard... I've tried a few times but I can only come up with stuff that's embarrassingly wrong. I'll edit my latest try into the q in a moment

Comment: Find a line of text in a book, on a webpage, or wherever.  Point your left index finger at the beginning, your right at the end. -- When you see it...code it.

Comment: `std::reverse(array, array + strlen(array))`

Comment: @Barmar - added an answer.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - I could only figure out something with a temporary variable to hold stuff but it works :D :D

Comment: @RedAlert `strlen` yuck

Comment: If you implement swap yourself then you'll need a temporary.  If you use `std::swap` you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers guys - here's what I ended up coming up with. Seems like it works.

```
void reverseRelevantParts(char arr[], int size) {

int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    int temporary = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter/2; i++) {
            temporary = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[counter - i - 1];
            arr[counter - i - 1] = temporary;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: See my answer for a C++ (rather than C) version

Comment: hey @developerbmw - i'm pretty sure my answer is c++? could you explain why it's not, please? i'm fairly new to this all, cheers

Comment: Well your code is technically valid C++ (since C++ is largely a superset of C) but C++ has nicer ways to do these things.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard Library is your friend. Note that this will work for arrays of any type - simply change the types. Other answers using functions like `strlen` will only work for C-strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    auto arr = std::array<char, 5>{'1', '3', '2', 0, 0};
    std::reverse(arr.begin(), std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0));

    for (auto c : arr)
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: Using reverse doesn't really exercise knowledge of arrays or really teach anything about them.  So while it will accomplish the stated spec of the assignment I doubt very much it will accomplish the intended goal.

Comment: @CrazyEddie which is why the OP needs to do their homework :) They could probably get away with copying and pasting your answer but not mine.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that you tried and made your own answer...

```
char const* reverse(char * arr, int size)
{
    int beg = 0;
    int end = static_cast<int>(strnlen_s(arr, size)) - 1;

    while (beg < end) std::swap(arr[beg++], arr[end--]);

    return arr;
}
```